# Get friendly duration from current date and a date in the past

Tags: objective-c, date, time, difference, date-difference

Suppose right now, the date and time is `2015-01-10 10:30:00`. I have a date in the past like `2015-01-10 08:30:00` and another like `2015-01-09 15:00:00`.

Instead of displaying the date difference in number of days and seconds, I want to display something like `2 hours ago` or `Yesterday`. If the date is too far away, something like `December 2014` could be used. It's similar to the time in posts on popular social networks.

Is there an easy way or already existing piece of code for to achieve this or I will have to make my own implementation?

Thanks.

Edit: I'm working with objective-c. `NSTimeInterval secondsBetween = [date2 timeIntervalSinceDate:date1];` will return the time in seconds. I am more in search of an existing solution/library

Comment: With what programming language? Have you already tried anything yourself? Can you show us some code you've tried?

Comment: I'm working with objective-c. `NSTimeInterval secondsBetween = [date2 timeIntervalSinceDate:date1];` will return the time in seconds. I am more in search of an existing solution/library.

Comment: TTTTimeIntervalFormatter ?

Comment: the best way to achieve this is dividing `NSTimeInterval` between dates to number of second in week/day/hour but I can`t find this answer here